Devops Workflow and CORS for AWS Amplify & REST API
I've built a webapp on AWS Amplify that's been gaining some traffic locally. The webapp uses AWS Cognito to authenticate users, then users interface with my Lambda functions via a AWS Gateway REST API. Pretty simple, right.
Issue is, I'm not sure how to make a sustainable Devops workflow using these tools.
More specifically, my AWS Gateway REST API uses CORS. So I have to manually change the CORS within the AWS Lambda functions if I want to test/demo the webapp locally. This is a  huge barrier to rapid development considering the number of Lambda functions & REST endpoints I have setup. Creating a new stage for the REST API would be smart, but the problem is that I return (identical) CORS in both the REST API "Options" & the Lambda function's response.
Solving this problem would be huge, in case any of you have any insight to share.
This is also a symptom of lacking a Devops workflow, so any input/advice there is also greatly appreciated; besides the specific problem I'm facing.
Many thanks.
